# convert delegate from c# to vb.net

Tags: vb.net, delegates

I'm having trouble converting a C# delegate to VB.NET.

How can this be done?

```
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _twain = new Twain(new WinFormsWindowMessageHook(this));
        _twain.TransferImage += delegate(Object sender, TransferImageEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.Image != null)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = args.Image;

                widthLabel.Text = "Width: " + pictureBox1.Image.Width;
                heightLabel.Text = "Height: " + pictureBox1.Image.Height;
            }
        };
        _twain.ScanningComplete += delegate
        {
            Enabled = true;
        };
    }
```

Comment: Which version of VB.Net do want to target?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither of those methods seem to use any context in the constructor itself, so I would convert each anonymous method into a "normal" method in your VB code (which should be straightforward), and then use something like this in your constructor:

```
AddHandler _twain.TransferImage, AddressOf(TransferImageHandler)
AddHandler _twain.ScanningComplete, AddressOf(ScanningCompleteHandler)
```

The methods should have the same signature as the events they're handling.